# Load gtags with given gtags root

Tags: vim, gnu-global

I have a log file(in say /home/logs) with file names and line numbers. I want to look up the files in a project rooted at say /x/projects/project12/ .
How do use gtags to look up files while log file is opened in vim ?
One clumsy way is to copy log file in project directory.

Is there a better way, something like while log file is opened in vim I set gtagsroot to /x/projects/project12/ and all lookups happen in that project ?

EDIT: gtags were created by gtags command in project root.

Comment: This really sounds like you just need to change your working directory with `:cd` or `:lcd`. Would that work? We dont really know how you are using gtags/gnu global so would setting `'tags'` for the log buffer to point to your project root work? Are you using `gtags-cscope`?

Comment: I have file similar to https://github.com/choplin/dotfiles/blob/master/_vim/plugin/gtags-cscope.vim . So C-\ f should open file under cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The gtags-scope.vim plugin uses `global -pq` to find the location of the `GTAGS` file. The easiest solution would be to set your current working directory to your project directory via `:cd ~/project`.

But there is a better way! Just use `gf`. You can add your project root to the `'path'` option and all `gf`, `<c-w>f`, `:find`, and friends will just work. Do this doing the following:

```
:set path+=~/project
```

or if you just want to adjust the `'path'` option for just that buffer do:

```
:setlocal path+=~/project
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'path
:h gf
:h :cd
```